# Loop through array in specific order

Tags: bash

I have an array that may or may not contain `BMC`, and I'm looping through each element of the array.  If it does contain `BMC` I want `BMC` to be the last iteration of the loop.

The array is created with command line options so I don't think I can enforce the order of creation without making significant changes.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while getopts cnBba opt; do
    case $opt in
        c)  options+=(CPLD);;
        n)  options+=(NIC);;
        B)  options+=(BMC);;
        b)  options+=(BIOS);;
        a)  all=true;;
    esac
done


# This is probably really confusing because it's redacted but this script also
# allows for -a to be used and then I'll query an endpoint that gives me a list
# of all available firmware for the given server.  It could return some or all
# of the possible options in no particular order.
mapfile -t types < <(curl some_firmware_endpoint)
if [[ $all == true ]]; then
    options=($(printf '%s\n' "${types[@]}" NIC | sort -u))
fi

for opt in "${options[@]}"; do
    echo "option is $opt"
done
```

Which produces this output:

```
$ ./script.sh -Bbcn
option is BMC
option is BIOS
option is CPLD
option is NIC
```

But I would like this output:

```
$ ./script.sh -Bbcn
option is BIOS
option is CPLD
option is NIC
option is BMC
```

---

I sort of have a solution but it's creating a null element in the array, which I'm sure I could further deal with but there may be a more correct way to do this.

My solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while getopts cnBba opt; do
    case $opt in
        c)  options+=(CPLD);;
        n)  options+=(NIC);;
        B)  options+=(BMC);;
        b)  options+=(BIOS);;
        a)  all=true;;
    esac
done


# This is probably really confusing because it's redacted but this script also
# allows for -a to be used and then I'll query an endpoint that gives me a list
# of all available firmware for the given server.  It could return some or all
# of the possible options in no particular order.
mapfile -t types < <(curl some_firmware_endpoint)
if [[ $all == true ]]; then
    options=($(printf '%s\n' "${types[@]}" NIC | sort -u))
fi

if [[ "${options[@]}" =~ BMC ]]; then
    options=("${options[@]/BMC/}" BMC)
fi

for opt in "${options[@]}"; do
    echo "option is $opt"
done
```

Which produces:

```
$ ./script.sh -Bbcn
option is
option is BIOS
option is CPLD
option is NIC
option is BMC
```

---

The -a all option:

The all option will query an endpoint (basically just a json object) that will have a list of firmware available for a server type.   Some servers may only return `BIOS BMC`, some may return `BIOS BMC NIC CPLD SATA StorageController` or even more.  Because of the way the json object is organized most of them will list NIC firmware separately so I'm manually adding that when -a is used and I handle that error separately if there is no firmware for that particular NIC, and then since *some* of them also have NIC I do a `sort -u` to remove NIC if it's listed twice.

Answer (score 2):

Create the array later.  If the `-a` option is used, call your enpoint and rearrange the `BMC` string last using `sed`. If it's not used, create the array from the given command line options.

(Note: I'm using literal tabs for indentation here. The here-document won't work properly with spaces. Or you can manually remove the indentation.)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Fake endpoint response.
get_valid () {
        cat <<-END_LIST
                BIOS
                BMC
                tiny green peas
                CPLD
                MICROBE
        END_LIST
}

a_opt=false
unset -v c_opt n_opt B_opt b_opt

while getopts acnBb opt; do
        case $opt in
                a)      a_opt=true      ;;
                c)      c_opt=1 ;;
                n)      n_opt=1 ;;
                B)      B_opt=1 ;;
                b)      b_opt=1 ;;
                *)      :       # error handling here
        esac
done


if "$a_opt"; then
        readarray -t options < <(
                get_valid |
                sed -e '/^BMC$/{ h; d; }' \
                    -e '${ p; g; /^$/d; }'
        )
else
        options=(
                ${c_opt:+CPLD}
                ${n_opt:+NIC}
                ${b_opt:+BIOS}
                ${B_opt:+BMC}
        )
fi

printf 'Option: "%s"\n' "${options[@]}"
```

Without `-a`: The `options` array in the code above is created with the strings corresponding to each parsed option in the order listed in the assignment.  A string is included in the array only if the corresponding `_opt` variable is set (the actual value is unimportant).

With `-a`: The `options` array is created from the strings returned from the endpoint.  If the string `BMC` is found in the output of the endpoint (on a line by itself), it is moved to the end by saving it in the hold space until the last line is processed.

```bash
$ bash script -bBcn
Option: "CPLD"
Option: "NIC"
Option: "BIOS"
Option: "BMC"
```

```bash
$ bash script -a
Option: "BIOS"
Option: "tiny green peas"
Option: "CPLD"
Option: "MICROBE"
Option: "BMC"
```

Comment: Thanks, I've modified my question to include another wrench thrown into the gears of my poor coding choices.

Comment: @jesse_b Updated.

Comment: Yes but the endpoint I'm querying wont always return all available options, for example on some machines might only return BIOS and BMC.

Comment: @jesse_b Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Special case being special, you could just manually punt that one after the loop:

```
...
handle_opt() {
    echo "option is $1"
}

do_BMC=0
for opt in "${options[@]}"; do
    if [[ $opt = BMC ]]; then do_BMC=1; continue; fi
    handle_opt "$opt"
done

if [[ $do_BMC= 1 ]]; then
    handle_opt "BMC"
fi
```

---

Alternatively, fix the order of processing for the options in a constant array, and have e.g. an associative array telling which ones are enabled. Though this does mean reading the input from the external program isn't as simple as one `mapfile`. (This can be seen as a variant of Kusalananda's solution).

Untested, but you get the idea:

```
order=(CPLD BIOS NIC BMC)  # keep BMC last
declare -A options         # associative array

while getopts cnBba opt; do
    case $opt in
        c)  options[CPLD]=1 ;;
        n)  options[NIC]=1  ;;
        B)  options[BMC]=1  ;;
        b)  options[BIOS]=1 ;;
        a)  all=true ;;
    esac
done

if [[ $all == true ]]; then
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        options[$line]=1;
    done < <(curl some_firmware_endpoint)
fi

for opt in "${order[@]}"; do
    if [[ "${options[$opt]}" != 1 ]]; then continue; fi

    handle_opt "$opt"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remember you got `B` when looping through the options then populate `options[]` later, e.g. using a scalar variable:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while getopts cnBba opt; do
    case $opt in
        c)  options+=(CPLD);;
        n)  options+=(NIC);;
        B)  gotB=1;;
        b)  options+=(BIOS);;
        a)  all=true;;
    esac
done

# mapfile and it's associated loop would go here

(( gotB )) && options+=(BMC)

for opt in "${options[@]}"; do
    echo "option is $opt"
done
```

```
$ ./script.sh -Bbcn
option is BIOS
option is CPLD
option is NIC
option is BMC
```

```
$ ./script.sh -bcn
option is BIOS
option is CPLD
option is NIC
```

or if your bash version supports `-v` you could keep a separate array of options as you `getopts` them and later test for `B` being an index in that:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A opts

while getopts cnBba opt; do
    opts["$opt"]=''
    case $opt in
        c)  options+=(CPLD);;
        n)  options+=(NIC);;
        b)  options+=(BIOS);;
        a)  all=true;;
    esac
done

# mapfile and it's associated loop would go here

[[ -v opts[B] ]] && options+=(BMC)

for opt in "${options[@]}"; do
    echo "option is $opt"
done
```

or save any options you want to add on at the end in a different array first then populate `options[]` from that array later:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while getopts cnBba opt; do
    case $opt in
        c)  options+=(CPLD);;
        n)  options+=(NIC);;
        B)  deferred+=(BMC);;
        b)  options+=(BIOS);;
        a)  all=true;;
    esac
done

# mapfile and it's associated loop would go here

for opt in "${deferred[@]}"; do
    options+=("$opt")
done

for opt in "${options[@]}"; do
    echo "option is $opt"
done
```

Add the `mapfile` and associated loop between the `while getopts` and where I add `B` to `options[]` in any of the above scripts as mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers all.  I ended up going with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while getopts cnBba opt; do
    case $opt in
        c)  options+=(CPLD);;
        n)  options+=(NIC);;
        B)  options+=(BMC);;
        b)  options+=(BIOS);;
        a)  all=true;;
    esac
done

mapfile -t types < <(curl some_firmware_endpoint)
if [[ $all == true ]]; then
    options=($(printf '%s\n' "${types[@]}" NIC | sort -u))
fi

if [[ "${options[@]}" =~ BMC ]]; then
    options=("${options[@]/BMC/}" BMC)
fi

for opt in "${options[@]}"; do
    [[ -z "$opt" ]] && continue
    echo "option is $opt"
done
```

If options contains `BMC` it will be removed and then readded at the end, and then since that creates a null element I just check if the element is null within my loop and skip that iteration.